# razor syntax within quoted javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

How do I escape my javascript so I can perform the following?

This is an example:

It's not outputting 'Month1', 'Month2' etc. and instead it is actually outputting 'Month@i'.

```
     @for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       { 
           <text>
           {
               field: 'Month@i',
               title: ,
               width: 10
           },
           </text>
       }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problems is that Month@i is wrongly interpreted as an email address, so you need to use explicit expressions @(...) to tell the Razor that this is a code expression.
This is the best solution:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{ 
    <text>
    {
        field: 'Month@(i):',
        title: ,
        width: 10
    },
    </text>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can format the field name in the top of your for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{ 
    var field = string.Format("Month{0}", i);
    <text>
    {
       field: '@field',
       title: ,
       width: 10
    },
    </text>
}
```